# NullPointerException Thrown on TextView

Tags: android, debugging, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException near the beginning of my onCreate method in my Android app. I am getting that the clock TextView variable in null, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

My code:

```
//Some of the variables declared outside of any method:
EditText filename;
TextView clock;
private Handler clockHandler = new Handler();

//onCreate and the onClick method that flips the view and starts the timer:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createLayout();
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.marker_flipper);
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
    time_marks = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.time_marks);
    stop_time_marks = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stop_time_marks);
    times = new ArrayList<String>();
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
            clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock);
            mark = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mark);
            stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clockHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
        }
    });
```

createLayout Method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void createLayout() {
    // Define Screen Size
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    // Define LayoutParams
    LayoutParams parentParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams clockParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, display.getHeight() / 8);
    clockParams.gravity = (Gravity.CENTER);
    // Root Element
    ViewFlipper flipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
    flipper.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    flipper.setId(R.id.marker_flipper);
    // Child 0
    com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout markerStart = new com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout(
            this);
    markerStart.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    markerStart.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Children of markerStart
    Button start = new Button(this);
    start.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, display.getHeight() / 2));
    start.setText("Start Marking");
    start.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),
            Typeface.BOLD);
    start.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 4);
    start.setId(R.id.start);
    markerStart.addView(start);
    flipper.addView(markerStart);
    // Child 1
    com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout marker = new com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout(
            this);
    marker.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    marker.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Children of marker
    Button mark = new Button(this);
    mark.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (display.getHeight() / 10) * 4));
    mark.setText("Mark Time");
    mark.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),
            Typeface.BOLD);
    mark.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 5);
    mark.setId(R.id.mark);
    marker.addView(mark);
    Button stop = new Button(this);
    stop.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            display.getHeight() / 10));
    stop.setText("Stop Marking");
    stop.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 20);
    stop.setId(R.id.stop);
    marker.addView(stop);
    TextView clock = new TextView(this);
    clock.setLayoutParams(clockParams);
    clock.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    clock.setText("");
    clock.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    clock.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 10);
    clock.setId(R.id.clock);
    marker.addView(clock);
    ScrollView sv1 = new ScrollView(this);
    sv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    LinearLayout marks = new LinearLayout(this);
    marks.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    marks.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    marks.setId(R.id.time_marks);
    sv1.addView(marks);
    marker.addView(sv1);
    flipper.addView(marker);
    // Child 2
    com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout markerStop = new com.jenglanddev.marktime.Scaling_Linear_Layout(
            this);
    markerStop.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    markerStop.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Children of markerStop
    Button save = new Button(this);
    save.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, display.getHeight() / 4));
    save.setText("Save Times");
    save.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),
            Typeface.BOLD);
    save.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 8);
    save.setId(R.id.save);
    markerStop.addView(save);
    Button reset = new Button(this);
    reset.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, display.getHeight() / 4));
    reset.setText("Reset");
    reset.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),
            Typeface.BOLD);
    reset.setTextSize(display.getHeight() / 8);
    reset.setId(R.id.reset);
    markerStop.addView(reset);
    ScrollView sv2 = new ScrollView(this);
    sv2.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    LinearLayout stopMarks = new LinearLayout(this);
    stopMarks.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    stopMarks.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    stopMarks.setId(R.id.stop_time_marks);
    sv2.addView(stopMarks);
    markerStop.addView(sv2);
    flipper.addView(markerStop);
    setContentView(flipper);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: gotta love null pointer questions

Comment: It would be better to show us how `createLayout` method works

Comment: It's hard for us to help look for a bug in your onCreate() method when you only give us part of it.

Comment: Post the full activity pls

Comment: I posted the full onCreate() and onClick() methods, as well as the createLayout() method.

Comment: Post the Exception. Tell us what line. Please give us the details.